# How to read 16bit png using Lua?

Tags: lua, png, torch

I am using Ubuntu and torch7 library to deal with 16bit images.

It would be best if Lua can read/write 16bit png files.

However, I found that if I try to read them by image.load function, it gives result of only higher 8 bit values.

Currently I'm using preprocessed binary files instead, but it is quite cumbersome.

Is there any way to read/write 16 bit png file with Lua?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick

The graphicsmagick package should work for 16-bit pngs.

You can install it via

```
luarocks install graphicsmagick
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the link.

Now I can read the 16-bit png file with gm.load

But when I try to write the output, with following code, it outputs 8-bit depth images.

--writing
img:save('output.png')

I cannot figure out how to specify output bit depth.

Could you show some example?

Answer (score 1):

I have some OpenCV bindings for torch7. Simply because OpenCV has better image resizing/warping/loading than the image library written in torch. It handles the 16bit png images fine.

They work on Height x Width x Channel images instead of the torch7 Channel x Height x Width images. This is no problem in practice, because they're convertible by transpose.

It's not documented properly but should be very useful to someone! (read the init.lua for a description).

https://github.com/Saulzar/lua---opencv